# Can not capture mouseover event while dragging on an svg

Tags: d3.js, svg, mouseover, drag, highlighting

What I need is to highlight one circle when Im dragging an arrow over it.
While dragging this are the color of the circles:
[circles now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBch9.png)

What I need is stg like this:
[Target Node highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UKsk.png)

I tried with **d3js mouseover event** on the circle, but is not being fired while dragging, and also tried with **css rule** ( :hover) over the circle with the same results.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: you may want to post some of your code.

Comment: We need to see those attempts if we're to offer advice on where you went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pointer-events

If you set the `pointer-events` parameter of your element you drag to `none`, then the other elements you hover onto, will trigger the mouseover event.

And when you finish the drag, set the parameter to `auto`.